# Problems with mediaElement.Source and absolute path

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a SL project that is simply the MediaElement. I embed this in my aspx page and do all the controling of the element from the aspx page throught the java to managed code bridge. I had all my video files in the project as resources for testing but now want to move them out to the server where they will live. The server is in a different domain from my development box but I have access. I can see my files by going to the "run" command and typing that path as follows: "\mediaserver.otherdomain.com\Content\MyVideo.wmv" I can access the folder and view the video's fine from my computer. However, when I do my

```
`mediaElement.Source = new Uri(MediaPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);`
```

in my code to load the video into Silverlight video does not play. The Media path is "\MediaServer.OtherDomain.com\Content\MyVideo.wmv.  I have image files that I reference using the same path "\MediaServer.OtherDomain.com\Content\MyVideo.jpg" and they display fine.

When I debug and look at the values set in the .Source propery I see:

```
Absolute Path = "/Content/MyVideo.wmv"
Absolute Uri = "file://MediaServer.domain.com/Content/MyVideo.wmv"
Host = "MediaServer.domain.com"
```

This all looks good, so why don't I see the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight does not allow you to use cross domain references out of the box.  You need to add an exception to do so.

If you're using SL4, look at [Making a Service Call Across Domain Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I found out the server that will be hosting the video files has IIS so I just set up a virtual directory and access them that way. "http://mediaserver.domin.com/content/myvidero.wmv" 

Thanks!